# Spark Executors all error and performance slowly degrades

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running spark in stand-a-lone mode, version 1.4.1.  I have 10 node cluster that is co-located with Cassandra.  I have a job that reads from a single Cassandra table, does 2 maps, and then writes the RDD to an Elasticsearch cluster using the elasticsearch-hadoop library provided by elasticsearch. Specifically the job looks like.  I don't think this important to problem, but for completeness...

```
val sc = new SparkContext(....)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "tablename")
.select("col1", "col2")
.map(c => caseclass(c.columnvalues(0), c.columnvalues(1))
.map(cc => Map(... construct map for es ... )
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "/index/type")
```

The job runs fine at first, but quickly starts to slow down after a few minutes.  Workers begin to start spending a lot of time in the `LOADING` state.  And all of the worker logs look similar to

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/08/15 18:55:08 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/08/15 18:55:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/15 18:55:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
16/08/15 18:55:09 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
16/08/15 18:55:09 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(spark); users with modify permissions: Set(spark)
16/08/15 18:55:09 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/08/15 18:55:09 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/08/15 18:55:10 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@10.0.5.33:56472]
16/08/15 18:55:10 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port 56472.
16/08/15 18:57:10 ERROR UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:spark (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1504)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
... 4 more
16/08/15 18:57:10 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

All of the workers show a status of `EXITED` eventually and all Tasks show as successful.  They just slow down to absolute crawl.  When I view the resource usage on all of the clusters they are not even close to being maxed out.

Any help with this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm. Does the cluster have ports open properly between driver -> worker and worker -> worker? Also, is this job ran under sufficient privileges on the worker nodes? Looks like the Spark user has issues connecting to the master. Trying telnet / nc from your workers to the master, it may be that the master is bring bound to the IP you expect it to.

Comment: It didn't.  I figured out just yesterday.  The ops team had closed a range of ports in our AWS security.  Once we reopened the ports everything worked just fine.  Thanks for the response.  I should have mentioned I had found a solution yesterday.